# Windows 10: Any way to quickly remove and then re-pair a specific Bluetooth device?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, powershell, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth mouse which I generally like a lot. However, when I use it with Windows, the mouse will sometimes take an *extremely* long time (think upwards of two minutes) to wake up after being left idle.

When this happens, I've found that the quickest way to get my mouse working is actually to remove the mouse from my Bluetooth devices completely, put the mouse in pairing mode, and pair it again. (Windows Key, type "Bluetooth", enter, tab tab tab tab, enter, enter, put the mouse into pairing mode, down, enter, tab, enter). This actually takes much less time then waiting for my mouse to wake up the normal way, but the sequence of keystrokes required is somewhat ridiculous.

Is there any way that I could use a single keyboard command to remove and re-pair the mouse? Perhaps I could assign a key to run a powershell script, for example.

I know that the best thing to do would be to find and fix the root cause of the problem--why does the mouse take so long to wake up in the first place--but I've tried that and I've given up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A keyboard command, no, there isn't one.

Comment: I was thinking I could have it run a script or something though. If I was in OS X, I would use bash or (more likely) applescript for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and record a macro for it.
Not the most elegant solution, but it should do the trick.

Another, and perhaps more interesting, way could be to install the [Bluetooth command line tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/).
Then use the new syntax in a script.

Note: The BD address in BR/EDR is static, so once you have the address of the mouse you can hard code it to your script.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of autohotkey, it works perfectly. Thanks you!